# Python LinkedList with 2 pointers

Tags: python-3.x, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, node_data):
        self.data = node_data
        self.next = None

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None

    def insert_node(self, node_data):
        node = Node(node_data)

        if not self.head:
            self.head = node
        else:
            self.tail.next = node


        self.tail = node

# Complete the printLinkedList function below.

    def printList(self):
        while self.head is not None:
            print(self.head.data)
            self.head = self.head.next

l = LinkedList()
l.insert_node(5)
l.insert_node(10)
l.insert_node(19)
l.printList()
```

I am trying to implement linkedlist using iterative method. I have 2 pointer(head, tail). so is there anyway to avoid using 2 pointers without recursion. and for printList function is is a good practice to use only head pointer. any feedback is appreciated

Comment: First, I see a problem with your `printList()` method: you're reassigning `self.head` with each node you print. Ultimately after printing it, you'll lose every node you've linked because the final node (`self.head.next`) will be `None`.

Answer (score 1):

With your current Linked List implementation, `self.tail` really isn't serving any purpose other than speading up insertion at the end. You could drop it by having all of your Linked List operations iterate from the head-pointer as you do in your `printList()` method. Bear in mind, though this does avoid recursion, this inherently forces all operations to be O(n); this isn't bad, though, as this is typical of simplistic Linked Lists.

The purpose of having the tail-pointer and nodes referencing previous-nodes is so that you can also support reverse-traversal. This is a simple optimization, but the improvement only becomes O(n/2) : good enough for short lists, but meaningless in larger lists. Again, that is the learning point of using such a structure over vectorized, ordered, and tree-like data structures.

Answer (score 0):

```
def getList(self):
    data = []
    currentNode = self.head
    while currentNode is not None:
        data.append( currentNode.data )
        currentNode = currentNode.next
    return data
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. In addition to the answer you've provided, please consider providing a brief explanation of why and how this fixes the issue.